# Install Windows 7 Touch Pack without touch screen

Tags: windows-7, touch, pixelsense

I've written an application based upon Surface and WPF. Now I want to test the application on an other computer. This computer has not a touch screen. Okay, I've downloaded the Windows 7 Touch pack from Microsoft. By starting the installer, I get an error: The installer needs a touch screen!

It is possible to start my application on my developers computer with multitouchvista.

Are there any possibilities to install the Windows 7 Touch Pack without a touch screen monitor? My idea is to use the this component(http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) to simulate the multitouch.

Comment: You mentioned "problem solved" - it may be useful to indicate **how** you solved this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the surface SDK, the surface simulator handles this. In addition to controlling multiple touches with *one* mouse, you can also plug in multiple mice to represent different touches.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that multitouchvista (http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com) does the trick. All you need to do is download mutlitouchvista, extract the files from the .zip, and then run the "install driver.cmd" from the "drivers" folder for either the x86 or x64. Be sure you have full admin rights or the driver won't install.